# Python for loop iteration and access over a list of list

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, iteration

Give the code below:

```
array = [[0, 2], [3, 4]]
for i in array:
    print '%d' % i[0][0]
```

I am getting the error: `TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`

but if I change to `print'%d' %i`
I get the error: `TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not list`

How am I supposed to cycle through the array and print the first and second value of each sub array?

Thanks

Comment: `i` is an element in `array`, therefore (in this case) it can only have one subscript.  BTW, `array` is the name of a standard library module so a bad choice for a variable name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
array = [[0, 2], [3, 4]]
for sub_array in array:
    print sub_array[0], sub_array[1]
```

or even better:

```
array = [[0, 2], [3, 4]]
for sub_array in array:
    print sub_array
```

Answer (score 2):

`i` is 1-dimensional.  Therefore:

```
 print '%d' % i[0]
```

PS. It's not really clear what is your desired  output.  This solution will print the first element of every list.

Answer (score 1):

You want `print '%d %d' % (i[0], i[1])`

Answer (score 1):

First, the statement `for x in y` loops over `y` and and assigns `x` to the value in `y` that you're currently looping on e.g.

`y = [1, 2, 3]
for x in y:
    print x`

would give the output: 1 2 3 4 thus, in your case

`array = [[0, 2], [3, 4]]
for i in array:
    print '%d' % i[0][0] 
    """
    i is [0, 2] on the first iteration
    making i[0] = 0
    i[0][0] -> TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not list
    changing this to i would obvious lead to i being a list that you're attempting to assign as a number -> TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not list
    """`

What you really meant to do was stop at `i[0]` making the code:

`array = [[0, 2], [3, 4]]
for i in array:
    print '%d' % i[0]`

As for your question, how to iterate over the array and print the values, well you can do something like:

`array = [[0, 2], [3, 4]]
for subarray in array:
    for element in subarray:
        print element`

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to keep your loop, you can do:

```
array = [[0, 2], [3, 4]]
for i in array:
    print '%d' % i[0]
```